# Can you recommend some free web services to play with?

Tags: web-services

I am studying usage of web services nowadays.

Can anyone recommend some free web services I can use to practice?

Comment: What response format are you looking to have returned? JSON, SOAP/XML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis) has a whole list of api's / web services you can play with.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to play with some online web services, visit the following site

[wcfspro.com/home/wcfservices](http://wcfspro.com/home/wcfservices)

those services are for testing